# Left-pad printf with spaces

Tags: c, formatting, printf

How can I pad a string with spaces on the left when using printf?

For example, I want to print "Hello" with 40 spaces preceding it.

Also, the string I want to print consists of multiple lines.  Do I need to print each line separately?

EDIT: Just to be clear, I want exactly 40 spaces printed before every line.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

If you want the word "Hello" to print in a column that's 40 characters wide, with spaces padding the left, use the following.

```
char *ptr = "Hello";
printf("%40s\n", ptr);
```

That will give you 35 spaces, then the word "Hello".  This is how you format stuff when you know how wide you want the column, but the data changes (well, it's *one* way you can do it).

If you know you want exactly 40 spaces then some text, save the 40 spaces in a constant and print them.  If you need to print multiple lines, either use multiple `printf` statements like the one above, or do it in a loop, changing the value of `ptr` each time.

Comment: dunno too much about format flags. but i suspect printf("%40s%s\n", "", ptr); can be used to pad it with 40 spaces too?

Comment: Yes, that would always give you 40 spaces before the contents of the pointer.  That's a nice solution, but if you have to do it a lot I think a constant with 40 spaces would be faster.  I don't know if the compiler is able to optimize printf formats.

Comment: Also, if you have an int variable 'n' that contains the number of spaces to include, you can use:  printf("%*s%s\n", n, "", ptr); to get a variable number of spaces.

Comment: And, to address the last part of the Q: yes, if you want each line of the data to be printed with 40 leading spaces, then you do need to segment the data so that each line is printed separately.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: of course the compiler can optimise printf formats. For instance, GCC optimises printf("%s\n", foo) and replaces it with puts(foo).

Answer (score 99):

I use this function to indent my output (for example to print a tree structure). The `indent` is the number of spaces before the string.

```
void print_with_indent(int indent, char * string)
{
    printf("%*s%s", indent, "", string);
}
```

Comment: I like your use of string literal concatenation to keep indentation separate from the rest of the printf format.  One suggestion: use an empty string instead of a single space for the indent string.  That way indent == 0 will work as expected. (i.e., `printf(..., indent, "", ...)`)

Comment: Note, Ray Hulha has removed the string literal concatenation, evidently in order to fix a "compiler issue".

Answer (score 63):

```
int space = 40;
printf("%*s", space, "Hello");
```

This statement will reserve a row of 40 characters, print string at the end of the row (removing extra spaces such that the total row length is constant at 40).
Same can be used for characters and integers as follows:

```
printf("%*d", space, 10);
printf("%*c", space, 'x');
```

This method using a parameter to determine spaces is useful where a variable number of spaces is required. These statements will still work with integer literals as follows:

```
printf("%*d", 10, 10);
printf("%*c", 20, 'x');
printf("%*s", 30, "Hello");
```

Hope this helps someone like me in future.

Comment: I got  `error: empty character constant` for `''`. Shouldn't it be `' '`?

Comment: Yes, it should.

Comment: @JinKwon any character, just as `"Hello"` could be anything, he should have used an example

Comment: This is awfully verbose if you have several arguments that all need the same number of spaces. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 28):

If you want exactly 40 spaces before the string then you should just do:

```
printf("                                        %s\n", myStr );
```

If that is too dirty, you can do (but it will be slower than manually typing the 40 spaces):
    `printf("%40s%s", "", myStr );`

If you want the string to be lined up at column 40 (that is, have up to 39 spaces proceeding it such that the right most character is in column 40) then do this:
    `printf("%40s", myStr);`

You can also put "up to" 40 spaces AfTER the string by doing:
    `printf("%-40s", myStr);`

Comment: like this comment for spaces after the string