# How do I append blank spaces to the end of a string using printf?

Tags: printf

How do I append blank spaces to the end of a string using `printf`?

I can't find any examples where spaces are appended to the right. [A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293438/left-pad-printf-with-spaces) I found use `printf` to add spaces to the *left* of the string instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use negative numbers to left-align (i.e. "pad" to the right).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    const char *s = "hello";
    printf("%30sworld\n", s);
    printf("%-30sworld\n", s);
}
```

This prints

```
                         helloworld
hello                         world
```

Comment: cool, the number of chars are going to be variable so can i pass something like this into printf? `"%-*", s, number` sorry, again i'm not on my compile PC.

Comment: whoops i just realized i can just turn the number into a negative number like this: number * -1. i'm sure this will work, will let you know when i get home.