# How to have absolute padding in printf()?

Tags: c

I tried

```
printf("%s %15s", string1, string2);
```

and I found out that this kind of left padding depends the distance from the first string, what if I want an absolute left padding counting from the left most?

Comment: It should depend on the distance from first string.What if the first string has 20 characters?Do you want second string to overlap the output of first string?It will mess things up.

Comment: but if I have many different length of string1s, then string2s will not align correctly

Comment: It's help ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293438/left-pad-printf-with-spaces

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to pad the first string on the right,  instead of padding the second sting on the left:

```
printf("%-15s %s",string1,string2);
```