# About left padding in C programming?

Tags: c, padding, space

I searched through the website already, but I can't seem to find the solution that pertains to my problem:

Example:

```
    printf("%s I love puppies", name);
```

this is my prinf statement, but how do I left pad in which it will add additional spaces with each for loop?

Edit:

```
    Hello  //int i is 0
      Hello  //int i is 1
        Hello  //int i is 2
          Hello  //int i is 3
```

I wanted to do something like this:
(in for loop)

```
     space += "  "   //where space is first initialized as ""
```

Is there a function that is similar to this (in java) in C programming?

Edit: The thing is I have this :  printf("%s I love puppies", name);

I was thinking of using int space = i (according to the loop counter) and then do printf("%s", space, "%s I love puppies", name); in printf but it says I have too many arguments...

Comment: Can you update the question to reflect where you want "space" to go? In any case, it seems like the solution to your problem would be to do something like 
    printf("%s%s", spacing, name)
and change spacing every iteration of the for loop if you want more spacing each time.

Comment: RTFM - 5 minutes on google will answer this question.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293438/left-pad-printf-with-spaces

Comment: Wait sorry. I have to change the first printf statement What if you have something after the %s printf statement? Do i need to have a string variable equal to the new string first?

Comment: please post the output you would like to obtain.   Perhaps perform a printf("  "); in a loop that uses the existing loop count as a limiting factor something like:  for( i=0; i<namelimit; i++ ){  for(j=0; j<i; j++ ) {printf("  ");}  printf("%s",name); }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can supply the `%s` format conversion with a length (just like any other format code). So `%10s` will print at least 10 characters.

By default, strings are padded on the left with spaces. (That's the same as other format codes, too.) You can't change the character that `printf` pads with, but you can get it to pad on the right by using a `-`: `%-10s`.

Length specifications can be replaced with a `*`, which will cause `printf` to use an `int` parameter prior to the parameter being converted, and use its value as the length. (You can do this with precision values as well.)

I imagine that what you are trying to do is a variable indent. Putting the above together, you can do it like this:

```
for (int indent = 0; indent < 20; ++indent) {
  printf("%*s%s\n", indent, "", the_string);
}
```

Comment: @Thankyouforyourhelp Click the check mark next to the answer to say you accepted it as the best answer to your problem.  That is how you say, "Thank you" here.  You can only select 1 though, so choose the one you think works best for you.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps perform a printf(" "); in a loop that uses the existing loop count as a limiting factor something like:

```
for( i=0; i<namelimit; i++ )
{ 
    for(j=0; j<i; j++ ) 
    {
        printf(" ");
    } 
    printf("%s\n",name); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for writing that ^^