# How to define number of spaces after '\n' in c

Tags: c

I want to print this:

```
    printf("please Choose: 1-For Checking what is the most popular number in the array\n               2-To sort your array from the smallest number to the biggest\n               3-To sort your array that even will be to your left and odd to the right\n               *Any other number will exit the program\n");
```

there is a way to define number of spaces after '\n' instead of typing lot of spaces?

Comment: You can always use `\t`

Comment: `printf("%8s\n", "");`

Comment: See this [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9448093/91757) for how to define a `print_with_ident` function.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
printf("%Ns\n", "");
```

where `N` is the number of spaces you want to display.

This way you are displaying an empty string preceded by `N` spaces.

```
printf("please Choose: 1-For Checking what is the most popular number in the array\n%8s2-To sort your array from the smallest number to the biggest\n%8s3-To sort your array that even will be to your left and odd to the right\n%8s*Any other number will exit the program\n", "", "", "");
```

Comment: This won't print Ron's original text....

Comment: @jpo38 I edited it

Comment: Great!! Thank you!