# How do I include a formal if statement into parameters in C?

Tags: c

For example, I have some code for a multiplication table, but to make it look a little neater, I have this %s in my print that spaces each number based on if it is a double digit number or a single digit number.

```
printf(" %d %s", columns * multiplier,
               (columns * multiplier < 10) ? "  " : " ");
```

The if statement I have is the shorthand version (and to my knowledge it can only have 2 conditions?), which is the only way I know how to include an if statement for a %s in a printf string, how would I make an if statement that can have multiple conditions? Like for triple digits or quadruple digits.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/293448/2970947

Comment: "the shorthand version" is called the ***ternary* operator**.

Comment: Make a new if statement before this printf statement and put the correct output needed into a variable.  Then just print that variable.

Comment: `cond1 ? cond1Val : cond2 ? cond2Val : cond3 ? cond3Val : "Range error."`

Comment: Focus on clean, readable, maintainable code and don't do that. Either format the string appropriately in the function before you call printf, or make a helper function to format the string that you call to provide the value for printf.

Answer (score 3):

Practically you'd probably use the minimal field width option to the printf formatter along with the 
left justification flag (-), e.g., `printf(" %-5d", 1);`, but if you want to use this as an opportunity to
play with the ternary, note that [its syntax](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.15p1) is:

```
conditional-expression:
                 logical-OR-expression
                 logical-OR-expression ? expression : conditional-expression
```

In English this means that you can nest it:

```
#define PR(X) printf(" %d %s", X,  \
            (X)<10 ? "   " :  \
            (X)<100 ? "  " :  \
            (X)<1000 ? " " : "" \
            )

#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf(" %-5d", 1);
    printf(" %-5d", 22);
    printf(" %-5d", 333);
    printf(" %-5d\n", 4444);

    //PRINTS:
    //1     22    333   4444 

    //The same thing with the ternary:
    PR(1);
    PR(22);
    PR(333);
    PR(4444);
    puts("");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like: 
    `x = a ? b : (c ? d : e)`
which is equal to:

```
if(a){
     return b;
 }else if(c){
     return d;
 }else{
     return e;
 }
```

or

```
x = (a && b) ? c : d
```

which is equal to:

```
if(a && b){//both a and b are true
     return c
 }else{
     return d;
 }
```