# How do I align columns in C

Tags: c

I need to write a program that displays decimal values in octal, hexadecimal and symbols in 5 columns. (values 0-32 need to be given special codes). The program works, but the output needs to be nicely aligned. What should I do to align the columns and make it look neat?
Here's the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int n,i,u=1,a=0,b=255;

    printf("\272");
    i=printf("My program to draw the ASCII table:");
    printf("\272\n");
    printf("\310");
    for(n=0;n<i;n++)  printf("\315");
    printf("\274\n\n");

  for(;a<=b;a++)
  {
      switch(a)
             {
                case 0:
                    printf("%d %o %x NUL  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("%d %o %x SOH  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("%d %o %x STX  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    printf("%d %o %x ETX  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    printf("%d %o %x EOT  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    printf("%d %o %x ENQ  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    printf("%d %o %x ACK  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    printf("%d %o %x BEL  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    printf("%d %o %x BS  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    printf("%d %o %x TAB  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 10:
                    printf("%d %o %x LF  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 11:
                    printf("%d %o %x VT  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 12:
                    printf("%d %o %x FF  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 13:
                    printf("%d %o %x CR  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 14:
                    printf("%d %o %x SO  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 15:
                    printf("%d %o %x SI  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 16:
                    printf("%d %o %x DLE  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 17:
                    printf("%d %o %x DC1  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 18:
                    printf("%d %o %x DC2  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 19:
                    printf("%d %o %x DC3  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 20:
                    printf("%d %o %x DC4  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 21:
                    printf("%d %o %x NAK  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 22:
                    printf("%d %o %x SYN  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 23:
                    printf("%d %o %x ETB  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 24:
                    printf("%d %o %x CAN  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 25:
                    printf("%d %o %x EM  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 26:
                    printf("%d %o %x SUB  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 27:
                    printf("%d %o %x ESC  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 28:
                    printf("%d %o %x FS  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 29:
                    printf("%d %o %x GS  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 30:
                    printf("%d %o %x RS  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 31:
                    printf("%d %o %x US  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 32:
                    printf("%d %o %x SPACE  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                case 127:
                    printf("%d %o %x DEL  \272  ",a,a,a);
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("%d %o %x %c  \272  ",a,a,a,a);
                    break;
             }

    if((a+1)%5==0) printf("\n");
  }
}
```

And here's the output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjPF5.png)

Comment: `printf` takes width specifiers, like `%10d` for ten characters and a decimal value.

Comment: That's also not ASCII but DOS ANSI.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer on how to left-pad with spaces to fixed column width:
[Left-pad printf with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293438/left-pad-printf-with-spaces)

Comment: I tried adding the code `printf("%20s","%d %o %x %c  \272  ",a,a,a,a);` ,and the formatting works, but now it displays "%d $o %x %c" instead of the values

Comment: @HoloBump please enable compiler warnings. You have supplied five arguments for the first format specifier argument `"%20s"` and the other four are ignored.

Comment: @HoloBump the `format` string is always the first argument to `printf`.

Comment: @WeatherVane so how could i fix this problem? Could you write that one line correctly please?

Comment: `printf("%9d %9o %9x %9c \272 ",a,a,a,a);` but any field width is ignored if the content is too large to fit. In other words, it breaks the formatting, rather than printing incorrect data by truncating it.